# APACHEDS LDAP error

Tags: jboss, ldap, apacheds

I want login to a flex application that it deployed on jboss 5.1.0 . 
During installation I configured ldap, with APACHEDS, and the software accept the credentials.
Now when i try to login JBOSS return me the following error:

```
LDAP: error code 80 - OTHER: failed for MessageType : SEARCH_REQUEST
```

Where is the problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is SEARCH_REQUEST that is returned I would suspect that the error is not finding the bind DN of your user.